# Failed to verify bitcode in Mapbox.framework

Tags: xcode, mapbox

**I have implement mapbox in the project , its ok work in simulator and device but when i am going to create build the issues has come . the issues attach here with screenshoot.**
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you will have to select your projects target, go from the General tab to the Build Settings tab, search for Enable Bitcode and set it to No. Of course, remember to do a new Archive before uploading it again.

I had many many issues with Mapbox and zero support from their team. I also had a bunch of error messages when uploading. One work around was using Carthage and manually adding in the frameworks instead of using Cocoapods. I hope this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Daniel for help.Its work for me. you save my time.thanks a lot.

Comment: During the fix the problem make sure delete the Derived Data and Archives.

Comment: I have Enable Bitcode set to No In App Side.. but With XCode 10 New build system I am getting same Error... Any help?

Comment: @tarun I’d probably go back to the stable Xcode 9 since 10 is in beta. As stupid as it sounds, restarting your machine sometimes fixes those kind of errors. If not, try looking at getting a hold of older or newer versions of the framework.

Comment: well sure ..but If I set my framework bitcode to NO and use that in my App project that issue is fixed ..